# 'q-text-as-data: command not found' error in a Bash script?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, scripts, python

I am a Linux novice, and I am currently trying to run a Bash Shell Script (see the very bottom) that manipulates files (code snippets) using the Windows 10 Linux Subsystem, but the script keeps failing at Step 5 (Line 32) and always shows the error below.

```
Error: ‘./snippets_filter.sh: line 32: q-text-as-data: command not found’.
```

I have tried the following:

- Re-installation of `q-text-as-data` with the following commands: `sudo apt-get update -y` and `sudo apt-get install -y q-text-as-data`.
- Listing of all packages to verify installation, using the following command: `dpkg -l | less`. And I can see that `q-text-as-data` comes under python as `python3-q-text-as-data` in the list.
- I have also tried printing the location of both `q-text-as-data` and `python3-q-text-as-data` to the terminal, but these locations are coming up empty.

Does anyone know what the issue is and how I can get Line 32 to run please?

Thank you for your time.

```
#/bin/bash
set -eu

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then 
    echo $0: usage: bash snippets_filter.sh snippets_dir 
    exit 1
fi

SNIPPETS_BASE_DIR=$1

TMP_KW=".snips_w_kw"
TMP_SYM=".snips_w_sym"
TMP_KW_SYM=".snips_w_sym_kw"
TMP_KW_SYM_LC=".snips_w_sym_kw_lc"

FULL_FILE="snips_sym_kw_6lines"
FULL_FILE_ID="snips_sym_kw_6lines_id"

echo "# Step 1/6 - Gathering list of snippets with keywords [ print or import ]"
grep -e 'print' -e 'import' -w -l -r "${SNIPPETS_BASE_DIR}" > "${TMP_KW}"

echo "# Step 2/6 - Gathering list of snippets with symbols [ ( or = ]"
grep -e '(' -e '=' -l -r "${SNIPPETS_BASE_DIR}" > "${TMP_SYM}"

echo "# Step 3/6 - Combining list of snippets with symbols or keywords"
cat "${TMP_KW}" "${TMP_SYM}" | sort -u > "${TMP_KW_SYM}"

echo "# Step 4/6 - Gathering line counts of those snippets (this will take a while)"
cat "${TMP_KW_SYM}" | xargs -I{} -n1 sh -c 'echo -n "{} "; grep -c . {}' > "${TMP_KW_SYM_LC}"

echo "# Step 5/6 - Getting list of IDs with > 6 lines and containing symbols and keywords"
q-text-as-data "select x.c1 from ${TMP_KW_SYM_LC} x where x.c2 > 5" > "${FULL_FILE}"
cat "${FULL_FILE}" | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | cut -d'.' -f2 | rev > "${FULL_FILE_ID}"

echo "# Step 6/6 - Cleanup - Removing tmp files"
rm "${TMP_KW}" "${TMP_SYM}" "${TMP_KW_SYM}" "${TMP_KW_SYM_LC}"
```

Comment: You are missing a `!` on the shebang, typo?

Comment: I have just looked inside the packages and it seems it's just named `q` not `q-text-as-data`,  but I could be wrong.

Comment: use xargs like this instead `xargs -I {} -n 1 sh -c 'echo -n "$* "' _ {}`

Comment: Hey @bac0n, I tried 'q' and it seemed to have worked, although I am currently not sure what the difference is but I guess I will have to read up on it to find out. Thank you so much for your assistance. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: It seems there may have been an *alternative* link to q-text-as-data but when or why it is no more I don't know.

Comment: I agree with you, @bac0n. The script was used as is in a previous project in 2019, so, yes, the alternative link you mentioned must have existed at some point.